# Include GCM sdk to cocoapod project

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-messaging, cocoapods

I already have a podsfile importing several other projects as frameworks, which works pretty nicely. Unfortunately it is not possible to install the gcm ios library as a framework. What is the way to go here? Just drag and drog the gcm pod into the project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a setup guide for both objective-c and swift on the developers site of gcm, it can be found here - https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client?ver=swift

`pod init`

Open the Podfile created for your application and add the following:

`pod 'Google/CloudMessaging'`

Save the file and run:

`pod install`

This creates an .xcworkspace file for your application. Use this file for all future development on your application.